# Modify a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have a function that takes two parameters and using these two parameters it returns a dictionary with the arguments of the function as the KEY and VALUE of the dictionary. But, I want this function to update or add a new item to the dictionary when the function is called again with a new set of arguments. How can I do so?

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: `def make_album(artist_name, album_title):
    return {artist_name: album_title}

print(make_album('Artist', 'Song'))`

Comment: you can add a third parameter which stores the dictionnary and then add the params back

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should give expected result:

```
discography = {}

def make_album(artist_name, album_title, didi):
  didi[artist_name] = album_title
  return didi

print(make_album('Artist', 'Song', discography))
```

or if you want an album to have multiple songs:

```
from collections import defaultdict
discography = defaultdict(list)

def make_album(artist_name, album_title, didi):
  didi[artist_name].append(album_title)
  return didi

print(make_album('Artist', 'Song', discography))
```